# Getting error while launching the remote spark jobs from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

When I'm trying to launch the remote spark jobs onto the CDH cluster from eclipse, the job is getting killed and when I see the logs of the container I'm seeing below error

```
Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Wed Apr 05 10:56:13 +0530 2017

Log Length: 87

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher


Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Wed Apr 05 10:56:13 +0530 2017

Log Length: 0
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks In advance

Comment: How you launch your application?

Comment: sorry, when I say launch it means I'm submitting the jobs from eclipse which is on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the classpath of the yarn in the spark context creation code